# Installing older version of gcc

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, ubuntu

I want to install gcc 4.1.2 on my Ubuntu 64 bit system, which currentcly has gcc 4.4. I want to keep on using the current gcc, but want to add gcc 4.1.2 as well. Any simple way to do it, that is install gcc 4.1.2 on my system?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/ seems more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Easy, just take it from an archive of the older Ubuntu releases. For example, my machine (still running natty) has

```
edd@max:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/g++-*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 242752 2010-09-10 04:16 /usr/bin/g++-4.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 263240 2011-03-31 15:22 /usr/bin/g++-4.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275856 2011-04-18 09:25 /usr/bin/g++-4.5
edd@max:~$
```

The 4.1.* series had some issues.  Even g++-4.2.1, the default on OS X, is not all that great.   But you should definitely have the option of installing this.

When you do this, by all means go the package management route of installing proper dependencies.  You will get matching packages for the other dependencies too.

In other words, you need to adjust `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to an older release that had this version.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.1=4.1.2 gcc-4.4
```

seems the straightforward solution to me. Since @DirkEddelbuettel noted that newer Ubuntu distributions dropped it, add an older distribution that has gcc-4.1 to your /etc/apt/sources.list. [The Ubuntu people maintain a great website](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/gcc-4.1) for looking that up; hardy, lucid and maverick seem great.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem: 4.1.2 is no longer in the (current) archive.

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.1=4.1.2-27ubuntu1 gcc-4.1-base=4.1.2-27ubuntu1 cpp-4.1=4.1.2-27ubuntu1 g++-4.1
```

Other way is to download gcc 4.1.2 and dependent libraries, and compile it yourself.

Comment: No, only if you adjust the repository to point back to a distro version that add the older one.

Answer (score 0):

Once installed see others:

Use the -V flag to run a particular version:

```
-V <version>             Run gcc version number <version>, if installed
```

Comment: You can also just call gcc-4.x for particular versions of x, eg via the CC variable in Makefiles or as an env. var.