# How to install previous version (4.4.7) of gcc/g++ via apt-get in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, g++-4.7

Due to legacy issues I have to install the gcc/g++ version 4.4.7 in my current Ubuntu-gnome 14.04 32 bit virtual machine.

The default update via apt-get install is the 4.8.2 which is a "no go" work for this project.
I've removed it (apt-get remove) . The downloaded and tried to install the 4.4.7 source but it requires to many dependencies.

Via apt-get install I've tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
```

The download/install is quite fast and when checkign gcc version it give indication that no gcc is installed to run the

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

If I do this I'll get the 4.8version.

All above also applies to g++.

Comment: Why do you need GCC 4.4.7? Uou could install several versions of GCC and use explicitly `g++-4.7` or `gcc-4.4` §....

Comment: Take a look at this stackoverflow [installing older version of gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854752/installing-older-version-of-gcc) and [installing older version of gcc using apt-get](http://superuser.com/questions/596197/installing-older-version-of-gcc-using-apt-get) on superuser.  this questions really belongs to superuser or perhaps to ask ubuntu.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I went for your solution. Yet i thought it was possible doing versions-install via apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled the code with the following flag which solved the problem:

```
g++-4.4.7
```

It compiles for a specific version. (in this case 4.4.7)

Comment: this don't work for me: `g++-4.6.3: command not found`. can you help on the command syntax?

Comment: That's the syntax, maybe you don't have the 4.4 version installed. First try the command g++-4.4 and check if it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

To install a specific version use `sudo apt-get install package=version`. Or use **synaptic package manager** which allows you to install specific versions.